# Jest can't advance timers related to Date

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to advance in time. I tried making this simple test:

```js
it.only('Advance in time', async() => {
  console.log('primer clg', new Date(Date.now()).toISOString())
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
  console.log('segundo clg', new Date(Date.now()).toISOString())
})
```

But const `pepe` is always the same time... what I'm doing wrong? How can I advance in time?

```
console.log
    2022-04-06T19:08:12.795Z

console.log
    2022-04-06T19:08:12.795Z
```

Answer (score 4):

From the doc [Advance Timers by Time](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks#advance-timers-by-time):

> `jest.advanceTimersByTime(msToRun)`. When this API is called, all timers are advanced by `msToRun` milliseconds. All pending "macro-tasks" that have been queued via `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, and would be executed during this time frame, will be executed.

This API is **not** used to fast forward `Date`. It's used for advanced the timers set by [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) or `setInterval()`

For Date testing, you probably need to mock date, so that your test code does not depend on system time. Then you can run your test code in any CI/CD servers which have different OS and timezones.

You can call `jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce` multiple times to mock different return values.

`mockDate1` is the return value of the **first** call to `Date.now()`, `mockDate2` is the return value of the **second** call to `Date.now()`. Both of them have fixed timestamps.

```js
describe('first', () => {
  it('Advance in time', async () => {
    const mockDate1 = new Date(1649272092795);
    const mockDate2 = new Date(1649272092795 + 1_000);
    jest.spyOn(global.Date, 'now').mockReturnValueOnce(mockDate1).mockReturnValueOnce(mockDate2);
    console.log('primer clg', new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()); 
    console.log('segundo clg', new Date(Date.now()).toISOString());
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71772373/index.test.js
  first
    ✓ Advance in time (14 ms)

  console.log
    primer clg 2022-04-06T19:08:12.795Z

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71772373/index.test.js:6:13)

  console.log
    segundo clg 2022-04-06T19:08:13.795Z

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71772373/index.test.js:7:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.867 s, estimated 1 s
```